# workon <env_name> does not activate virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I'm working on a Winodws 10 machine and using Python 3.6. `workon` command would give me a list of virtual environments on my computer, but when I type `workon <env_name>` nothing happens, the virtual environment is not activated. Could someone tell me how to fix it?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

workon is a Batch Script, so it must be run in cmd, not in PowerShell. Switch to cmd first and try again